# How to access the actual input html of the login form

Tags: wp-login-form

I'm designing a custom login template and I need a way to access the `<input>` html so I can add a label inside the input. I understand the use of `wp_login_form()` but that only lets me set the default lables outside the input to blank. I need to add the `onfocus` and `onblur` attributes to the html. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this basic *trick:* Close brackets, open again, insert what you need, close again.

Real life example:

```
$args = array( 
    // some args for the login form
    'value_username' => 'User Name" onBlur="whatever" onFocus="anotherfoo';
);
wp_login_form( $args );
```

So we closed the brackets after the Username, then added our additional attributes and left the quotes open at the end, so the `wp_login_form()` function can then close it by itself.